# Next.js: Jest encountered an unexpected token. Jest failed to parse a file. Crashing due to dot ( .{color: red} ) before a className in CSS files

Tags: testing, jestjs, next.js, token, testing-library

Jest encountered an unexpected token

```
Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
```

C:\NextSpeetar\speetar-react-frontend\node_modules\cropperjs\dist\cropper.css:11
.cropper-container {
^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

   5 | //Image Cropper
   6 | import Cropper from "react-cropper";
>  7 | import "cropperjs/dist/cropper.css";
     | ^
   8 | // Import Images
   9 | const src = "user-placeholder.png";
  10 | class ImageCropper extends Component {

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1479:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Image Cropper/ImageCropper.js:7:1)
```